# How to display a client ip address in a ListView when client connected and shutdown or wakeup client using c#

Tags: client, shutdown, wakeup

![Server][1]

Code Server : 
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TcpClient tcpclient;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress[] localip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach (IPAddress address in localip)
        {
            if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                textBox1.Text = address.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = "8888";
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpListener listenner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
        listenner.Start();
        tcpclient = listenner.AcceptTcpClient();

    }
```

![client][2]
Code Client
namespace CLIENT
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private TcpClient tcpclient;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        labelmessage.Visible = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tcpclient = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), int.Parse(textBox2.Text));
        try
        {
            tcpclient.Connect(ipe);
            if (tcpclient.Connected)
            {
                labelmessage.Visible = true;
                labelmessage.Text = "Conected...";
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use the TCPClient instance returned by the AcceptTCPClient() method.

```
     TCPClient _client = _listener.AcceptTCPClient();
    // Add to listview here for connection
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} connected", _client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()));
    // Same for others
```

**UPDATE**

```
TCPClient _client = _listener.AcceptTCPClient();
ListViewItem _item = new ListViewItem(_client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
listview1.Items.Add(_item);
```

More on working with ListView Controls

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx

Comment: i user WindowsFormsApplication.Can i use Console.WriteLine? i think it user for ConsoleApplication? and i want to add ipaddress to listview when client connected to server.

Comment: Unfortunately no you cannot use Console.WriteLine() in WindowsForms project. But It was an example how you can retrieve connected client IPs.

Comment: i want to show all IpAddress to Listview. can u hellp me?